# In intellj How do I restore git branches widget?

Tags: intellij-idea

For some unknown reason the git branches widget in the intellij status bar has disappeared.

How do I restore it?  I can still get to it via the main menu VCS->get->branches but this has disrupted things and is diconcerting.  There is no easy to discover item in "view" or "VCS" to restore ( or hide ) this widget.

Comment: It appears this is a bug, there was a bad character or someting in the vcs.xml file and it must have caused an exception or something that caused the menu widget not to be created.  For whatever reason restoring the vcs.xml file to a prior version caused the widget to be restored.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your entire `Status Bar` has disappeared.
Try this: `View > Status Bar`